# Weblogic server takes too long to start on windows

Tags: windows, weblogic

Weblogic server takes too long to start on windows.
I want it to run some soa applications in jdeveloper.
how to make it start faster?

I found some solutions for linux, but not for windows.
thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If more than 30 seconds, you have a problem.

Maybe the problem is not windows but the projects you previously uploaded to the server.
Try to create a new project from **jdeveloper** and press <kbd>Run</kbd> to start the integrated weblogic:

- if too much time → disable temporarily **windows firewall and/or your antivirus** and try again
- if less than 30 seconds → the production server contains too much projects, too much libraries to be loaded, etc.

I usually **HAD** a lot of problems because of the company antivirus system.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows, sometimes Weblogic binds itself to all network adapters configured on your machine running Windows. This doesn't happen on Linux systems.

All these redundant bindings end up eating a couple of seconds of startup time. To minimize it:

1. Start Weblogic: on JDeveloper, go to **Run** > **Start Server Instance**
2. Go to the admin console at http://localhost:7101/console and login as
   weblogic/weblogic1
3. On the left side navigation bar, select **Environment** > **Servers**
4. Select Default Server from the table
5. On the Listen Address field, enter: **127.0.0.1**
6. Restart Weblogic

This should reduce at least 30 seconds of startup time for Weblogic instances running on Windows.